# How to add rows to pandas dataframe with reasonable performance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an empty data frame with about 120 columns, I want to fill it using data I have in a file.

I'm iterating over a file that has about 1.8 million lines.
(The lines are unstructured, I can't load them to a dataframe directly)

For each line in the file I do the following:

- Extract the data I need from the current line
- Copy the last row in the data frame and append it to the end `df = df.append(df.iloc[-1])`. *The copy is critical, most of the data in the previous row won't be changed.*
- Change several values in the last row according to the data I've extracted `df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('column_name')] = some_extracted_value`

This is very slow, I assume the fault is in the append.

What is the correct approach to speed things up ? preallocate the dataframe ?

**EDIT:**

After reading the answers I did the following:

- I preallocated the dataframe (saved like 10% of the time)
- I replaced this : `df = df.append(df.iloc[-1])` with this : `df.iloc[i] = df.iloc[i-1]` (`i` is the current iteration in the loop).(save like 10% of the time).
- Did profiling, even though I removed the append the main issue is copying the previous line, meaning : `df.iloc[i] = df.iloc[i-1]` takes about 95% of the time.

Comment: What is the reason for 'Copy the last row in the data frame and append it to the end'. Do you need to have information from the previous row copied over to the new row? Or are you doing this just as a method to add a new template row

Comment: Why would you want to fill in an empty dataframe instead of creating a new one via `read_csv` ?

Comment: @jpp, I didn't mentioned csv. This is a complex binary file.

Comment: @Dillon, I need the data from the previous row in the next row

Answer (score 1):

You may need plenty of memory, whichever option you choose.

However, what you should certainly avoid is using `pd.DataFrame.append` within a loop. This is expensive versus `list.append`.

Instead, aggregate to a list of lists, then feed into a dataframe. Since you haven't provided an example, here's some pseudo-code:

```
# initialize empty list
L = []

for line in my_binary_file:

    # extract components required from each line to a list of Python types
    line_vars = [line['var1'], line['var2'], line['var3']]

    # append to list of results
    L.append(line_vars)

# create dataframe from list of lists
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['var1', 'var2', 'var3'])
```

Comment: You didn't mention how I copy the data from the previous row. Each line in the file adds information only to a few columns (~10). the rest of the 110 columns should be copied.

Comment: @OopsUser, You can copy at the end with `pd.Series.ffill`. But really you should mock up a small dataframe to illustrate what you get and what you want. Probably in a new question now that you've got 4 responses.

Answer (score 0):

The Fastest way would be load to dataframe directly via pd.read_csv()
Try separating the logic to clean out unstructured to structured data and then use pd.read_csv to load the dataframe.

You can share the sample unstructured line and logic to take out the structured data, So that might share some insights on the same.

Answer (score 0):

Where you use `append` you end up **copying** the dataframe which is inefficient. Try this whole thing again but avoiding this line: 
`df = df.append(df.iloc[-1])`

You could do something like this to copy the last row to a new row (only do this if the last row contains information that you want in the new row): 
`df.iloc[...calculate the next available index...] = df.iloc[-1]`

Then edit the last row accordingly as you have done 
`df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('column_name')] = some_extracted_value`

Answer (score 0):

You could try some multiprocessing to speed things up

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 
def YourCleaningFunction(line):
    for each line do the following 
    blablabla
    return(your formated lines with ,) # or use the kind of function jpp just provided

pool = ThreadPool(8) # your number of cores
lines = open('your_big_csv.csv').read().split('\n') # your csv as a list of lines
df = pool.map(YourCleaningFunction, lines)
df = pandas.DataFrame(df)
pool.close() 
pool.join()
```